# How can I do Holistic tracking on MLKit

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit, pose-detection

I was wondering if there are any plans to have the Holistic Detection (face + pose + hand tracking) implemented in MLKit, or if there is an easy and efficient way to add the face and the hand detection to the pose detection results.

Comment: So something like: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/holistic

Comment: Exactly that, but with MLKit tracking (I have a working MLKit pose detection, so I would prefer to stick with MLKit if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are looking at this indeed. However, since it is a very compute intensive set of tasks, we want to make sure it can run on a wide range of devices, rather than just flagship phones. If you are looking for this functionality today, I would go with the [MediaPipe solution](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/holistic.html) like you reference as well.